# Javascript add days, weeks or months to date of today

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

I've got a piece of code that cleans the browsers local storage.
What I want is to delete some keys based on parameters set.
An example: 
[image]
What this should be doing is to delete the localstorage on the first day of every month. Another example is when you fill in 5, 2, weeks. Then it should delete the localstorage every 5th day of every 2 weeks.
Now the main problem is adding the different periods to today's date in order to calculate the time when this needs to be done. I've been in over my head with this and tried some things (as you can see) but without results...
Anyone cares to help me out?
Thx!

Here's the code:

```js
function cleanLocalStorage() {
  var today = makeDate(todayDate()),
    deleteoption = localStorage.getItem("historydeleteoption"),
    lasthistoryclean = makeDate(localStorage.getItem("lasthistoryclean"));

  if (deleteoption == "days") {
    for (key in localStorage) {
      if (makeDate(key) < today.subtractDays(getHistoryRetain())) // days to keep data excluding today
        delete localStorage[key];
    }
  } else if (deleteoption == "period") {
    var historyretain = localStorage.getItem("historyretain"),
      historyresetday = localStorage.getItem("historyresetday"),
      historyresetperiod = localStorage.getItem("historyresetperiod"),
      historyresetperiodunit = localStorage.getItem("historyresetperiodunit"),
      cleaningday = "";

    if (historyresetperiodunit == "days") { ?
      // ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
    } else if (historyresetperiodunit == "weeks") { ?
      //  ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
      var cleaningday = lasthistoryclean + (historyresetperiod * 7);
    } else if (historyresetperiodunit == "months") { ?
      // ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
      var cleaningday = new Date(lasthistoryclean.setMonth(lasthistoryclean.getMonth() + historyresetperiod));
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem("lasthistoryclean", todayDate());
}

function todayDate() {
  var date = new Date();

  var dd = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
    mm = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), //jan is 0
    yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  return dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;
}

function makeDate(date) {
  var parts = date.split("-");
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="historydeleteoption" id="historydeleteoptiondays" value="days" onchange="greyOutHistoryDeleteOption()" checked="checked">
  <label for="historydeleteoptiondays" id="historydeleteoptiondayslabel">Max days to keep history: 
    <input type="number" name="historyretain" id="historyretain" value="30" min="0" max="999" style="width: 70px; margin: 2px 0;"><br>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="historydeleteoption" id="historydeleteoptionperiod" value="period" onchange="greyOutHistoryDeleteOption()">
  <label for="historydeleteoptionperiod" id="historydeleteoptionperiodlabel">Reset history on day 
    <input type="number" name="historyresetday" id="historyresetday" value="1" min="1" max="31" style="width: 70px; margin: 2px 0;"> of every 
    <input type="number" name="historyresetperiod" id="historyresetperiod" value="4" min="1" style="width: 70px; margin: 2px 0;">
    <select name="historyresetperiodunit" id="historyresetperiodunit" onchange="maxValuesDeleteOption()" style="margin: 2px 0;">
      <option value="days">days</option>
      <option value="weeks">weeks</option>
      <option value="months">months</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: If you have no problem in using an external library, I would suggest you to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) which really makes operations on dates (addition, subtraction, etc.) very easy.

Comment: Looks very promising. If that's what I'm going with then I can even convert some of the old code to use that (makedate and todaydate ore used in other places too). Thx

Answer (score 0):

I created this compact function:

```
function DateAdd(dfrom,anz,sel){
    var df = (dfrom || dfrom === 0) ? (typeof dfrom == "string" ? dfrom.replace(/(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\./,'$2/$1/') : dfrom) : "";
    df = df instanceof Date ? new Date(df-0) : (df === "" ? new Date() : new Date(df));
    var pj = {y:[1,"FullYear"],m:[1,"Month"],w:[7,"Date"],d:[1,"Date"],h:[3600000],n:[60000],s:[1000],ms:[1]};
    var s=pj[sel] || [1];
    var s1 = s[1] || "Time";
    df["set"+s1](df["get"+s1]() + parseInt(anz||0,10) * s[0]);
    return df;
}
```

Negative numbers are also allowed for anz parameter.

These values ​​are possible for the sel parameter:

- 'y' - years
- 'm' - months
- 'w' - weeks
- 'd' - days
- 'h' - hours
- 'n' - Minutes
- 's' - Seconds
- 'ms' - Milliseconds

Examples of use

```
//Add 3 Days to current Date
var date = DateAdd(new Date, 3, 'd');

//2 weeks after 2019-03-01
var date = DateAdd('2019-03-01', 2, 'w');
//Fri Mar 15 2019

//6 month after 1.3.2019
var date = DateAdd('1.3.2019', 6, 'm');
//Sun Sep 01 2019
```